# Meteor: Return unique records for a list filter

Tags: function, meteor, filtering

Hi I have a simple filter that allows a user to filter a list of posts based on a single dropdown of each list that has an associated post.

In other words, it allows you to filter all posts with a list of "Favorite drink places in williamsburg"

However, I only want that list to show in the dropdown once (right now it will show up 3 times if for example it has 3 posts associated with that list). Here's the helper function...

```
Template.userListsFilter.helpers({
  userlistsfilter: function() {
  var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
      return Posts.find({userId: currentUser, postlistid: { $exists : true }        },{sort:{postlistname:1} },{reactive:true});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the client, this can be done with function `uniq` from the underscore package. On the server this could be done using the node mongo driver directly.

I assume the unique field is `postListName`.  For the client the code could be like this.

```
var query = Posts.find({userId: currentUser, postListId: { $exists : true }},{sort:{postListName:1} });
var postListNames = query.map( function( post ){ return post.postListName });  
postListNames = _.uniq( postListNames );
```

Comment: Tried this but now it doesn't return anything? The field is postlistname (all lower case):

Comment: I put the code snippet on jsfiddle - couldn't remember how to format code blocks in comments in stackoverflow. http://jsfiddle.net/cmeethree/atqppLwp/

Comment: Had some typos with variable names sometimes camelCase.  Demo in [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/TWZJjyWibN4EQcSSc/uniq).

Comment: Ok cool thanks I'll take a look. I'm actually fixing a bigger problem in my upgrade (so am getting errors, won't start) from 0.9.3 to 1.0 so once I fix that I'll take another shot at this. Hopefully will resolve in the next day.

Comment: Ok fixed my upgrade issue. So when I tried to run in meteorpad I got an error: Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
      throw(ex);
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:182:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: The error was cause by leaving Meteor.startup() with no argument in the server code.  Fixed now.

Comment: Hmmm, ok yeah for some reason still not working for me. Even this doesn't work:

        `var query = Posts.find({userId: currentUser, postListId: { $exists : true }},{sort:{postlistname:1} });`

        `return query;`

I put my template on fiddle as well... http://jsfiddle.net/cmeethree/atqppLwp/

Comment: Ok played around a little more. It needed also to have reactive:true. Here's the final code:

        `var query = Posts.find({userId: currentUser, postlistid: { $exists : true }  },{sort:{postlistname:1} },{reactive:true}).fetch();`
        `return _.uniq(query, false, function(list) {return list.postlistname});`

Comment: Hi there, would you mind posting the code of what your html template looks like? I believe I've gotten the uniqueness filter working but now I'm not sure how to call the specific "postListName" variable in the html's #each iteration.